# Is it possible to reassign the "Pinch with thumb and three fingers" gesture to activate Dashboard instead of Launchpad?

Tags: trackpad, launchpad, dashboard, gesture

I don't really have a use for Launchpad, but the gesture to me makes sense for Dashboard. I experimented a little with BetterTouchTool, but it doesn't have the gesture available, and I'm not sure it would work well with the sequence of successive pinches and spreads to go from desktop Expose to overlay (normally Launchpad).

Ideally I'd like to see if there's a plist tweak that can be made somewhere that would keep the gesture behavior exactly the same, but substitute Dashboard for Launchpad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a plist modification you can do to alter the behaviour, but I do know that [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) will let you replace the [pinch zoom in/out gestures](http://blog.boastr.net/documentation-faq/new-bettertouchtool-documentation/#touchpadgestures) with custom actions. You can assign them to activate Dashboard instead of LaunchPad if you like or any number of other things. It can be a bit involved to set up, but it is very powerful in what it lets you override from the OS X defaults.

TUAW has [an article on customizing a Magic TrackPad using Better Touch Tool](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/01/19/customizing-a-magic-trackpad-using-bettertouchtool/) that demystifies it a bit.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, BTT's pinch in/out gestures are the two-finger pinch, not the thumb+three finger pinch that is used for Launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at **MagicPrefs** application.  It has all kinds of custom gestures.  Also the built in command in Apple OS for Dashboard is swiping from the left with 4 fingers on the trackpad.  With MagicPrefs you can change it to anything and also make custom actions.  I have used it from 10.8 and up.

http://magicprefs.com/

Comment: Thx! But is it have "thumb+three finger pinch" gesture?

Answer (score 0):

I tried BetterTouchTool (BBT), Jitouch, and MagicPrefs.  I've been using BBT for more than three years, making me unable to use any mouse other than Magic Mouse (you can't get a mouse with dozens of keys on it...)

For overall performance, BBT is the best and is totally free, it has plenty of gesture and plenty of preference with a perfect UI structure.

MagicPrefs (free) is worst among the 3 because it has very limited gestures and preferences in a neat UI that looks pretty but actually not good enough.

---

Jitouch is not free, BUT! it has two more gesture than BBT:

**3 finger PINCH** on trackpad ( this is what NReilingh may want )

and "directional" 2 finger pinch on magic mouse